# I have some printing problems. I get some black stains all over my pages. Help?

Tags: inkjet-printer

This a scanned page printed by me:

[image]

I refill the cartridges myself with a syringe, but I've never had this problem after 3-4 test pages. It usually goes away and prints fine. This time it just doesn't want to go away.

What could be the problem? Last time I refilled the black cartridge was 2 days ago, and I just refilled the color one.

PS: I have a multifunctional Canon MP 220 and the cartridge model is: CL-38.

Comment: Looks like your printer needs some cleaning.

Comment: Yummy pictures on that scanned page of yours! No, seriously though, maybe you have a bad cartridge head, can happen sometimes. That's why manufacturers don't want you to refill yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that was one refill too many for that cartridge - what make and model of printer?

EDIT:

There are different technologies for the cartridge design. Most Hewlett-Packard cartridges have the head included in the cartridges. Some other manufacturers prefer to keep the head as a part of the printer. What you could try is to use some acetone and a towel to clean the head. This might help. Just use a little acetone and try to use the capillary force to get the tint out of the head. This **might** help.

If you own a printer which has the head included in the cartridge it will look like there is some electrical circuit at the tip of the cartridge. In this case it might be less hassle to buy a new one and afterwards use this one with your refill tint.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be the park area for the head. Most ink-jets I've owned have a pad there to stop the ink drying, so yours may be soaked in ink.